# Use d3 custom layout in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

How to create custom layout in d3? I've read [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133010/custom-layouts-using-d3) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495664/custom-layout-in-d3-js) but still have the following errors. Can someone explain?

I write layout in a separate `gridLayout.js` and try to import this layout to a react component class.

```js
// Ver1
// Attempted import error: 'd3' does not contain a default export (imported as 'd3').
import d3 from 'd3';

d3.gridLayout = () => {
  function processGrid(data) {
    data.deleted = true
  }

  return processGrid;
}
```

```js
// Ver2
// custom layout just transform data in a certain way - normal js func
// Error: Line 2:  'gridLayout' is not defined  no-undef


export default gridLayout = () => {
  function processGrid(data) {
    data.deleted = true
  }

  return processGrid;
}
```